# Error while running python3 manage.py migrate_schemas --shared in Django multi-tenant application

Tags: django, django-models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
    
    # Add related_name arguments to avoid clash with auth.User
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        related_name='user_custom_set',
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='groups',
        help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.',
        related_query_name='user_custom',
    )
    
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        related_name='user_custom_set',
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='user permissions',
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
        related_query_name='user_custom',
    )
```

```
`your text`
SHARED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app
    'tenant', 

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # everything below here is optional
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

TENANT_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    "student",
    "teacher",
    "tenant",
    "account",

  
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app

    'tenant',


    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    "student",
    "teacher",
    "account",





   
)
```

```
python3 manage.py migrate_schemas --shared
\[standard:public\] === Running migrate for schema public
\[standard:public\] Operations to perform:
\[standard:public\]   Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites, student, teacher, tenant
\[standard:public\] Running migrations:
\[standard:public\]   Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0001_initial...
\[standard:public\]  OK

\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying account.0001_initial...
\[standard:public\]  OK
\[standard:public\]   Applying admin.0001_initial...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in \_execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "account_user" does not exist

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/manage.py", line 22, in \<module\>
main()
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
self.execute(\*args, \*\*cmd_options)
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
output = self.handle(\*args, \*\*options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenant_schemas/management/commands/migrate_schemas.py", line 33, in handle
executor.run_migrations(tenants=\[self.schema_name\])
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenant_schemas/migration_executors/base.py", line 58, in run_migrations
run_migrations(self.args, self.options, self.codename, public_schema_name)
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenant_schemas/migration_executors/base.py", line 31, in run_migrations
MigrateCommand(stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr).execute(\*args, \*\*options)
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
output = self.handle(\*args, \*\*options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
res = handle_func(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 356, in handle
post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
state = self.\_migrate_all_forwards(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in \_migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 249, in apply_migration
with self.connection.schema_editor(
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 166, in __exit__
self.execute(sql)
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 48, in execute
return super().execute(sql, None)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 201, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
return self.\_execute_with_wrappers(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in \_execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in \_execute
with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/Users/yabindrabhujel/Desktop/workspace/Django/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in \_execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "account_user" does not exist

I'm working on a Django multi-tenant application using the tenant_schemas package, and I
want to create custom user if custom user model create in inside of tenant app all fine when i create outside of tenant app get error . i want to create user model for each schema.

python3 manage.py migrate_schemas --shared
Save to grepper
However, during the migration process, I encountered the following error:

\[standard:public\]   Applying admin.0001_initial...
Traceback (most recent call last):

psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "account_user" does not exist
Save to grepper
```

It seems like the migration for the admin.0001_initial step is causing this issue. The error suggests that the "account_user" relation does not exist in the schema. The problem appears to be related to my custom user model and the interaction between the tenant_schemas and auth apps.

I have a custom user model defined in my user app that inherits from AbstractUser. Additionally, I'm using the --shared flag to migrate shared apps such as auth and admin.

How can I resolve this error and successfully run the migrate_schemas command with the --shared flag in my multi-tenant Django application?

Any help or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!